# How can I get my facebook personal profile posts using getAccessToken()?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

What I am actually trying to do is to retrieve my posts/statuses from my personal facebook profile page (this is not a fan page) and display them in my website. Also please note that every user that will visit my website should be able to view my statuses by means it does not have to do with authenticating them or something like that. This is something that needs to be generated server-side.

I am aware that you can retrieve a JSON string from a URL like this https://graph.facebook.com/MY_PROFILE_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN because I tried it from the facebook developers (Graph API Explorer) page and it is exactly what I need.

The thing is that when I generate the access token from the Graph API Explorer I can select permissions and it generates the token respectively according to permissions chosen, such as user_status, status_update, etc.

Now I want to accomplish this by using PHP-SDK but I have no idea how to generate an access token the same as the one I generate in the Graph API Explorer.

The basic way to do this is by calling getAccessToken() as shown here. The thing is that when I use the token generated from this simple method the JSON string returned will only show me my basic information.

```
$config = array(
  'appId' => 'MY_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET',
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$ACCESS_TOKEN = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

How can I add permissions for instance? Should I assign parameters somewhere? I spent quite a lot of time reading the facebook API documentation and some other forums but I did not find the answer that I need.

Finally if I get the right access token than I would simply retrieve the JSON string and parse it with what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need for add permissions in your code for login using the fb js sdk add in the scope this like this example:

```
$("#login").on('click',function(){
 FB.login(function(response){
 console.log(response);
 },{scope: 'email,manage_pages,read_insights'});
});
```

or in php fb sdk the next form:

```
<?php
require 'server/fb-php-sdk/facebook.php';

$app_id = 'APP_ID';
$app_secret = 'APP_SECRET';
$app_namespace = 'APP_NAMESPACE';
$app_url = 'https://apps.facebook.com/' . $app_namespace . '/';
$scope = 'email,publish_actions';

// Init the Facebook SDK
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => $app_id,
     'secret' => $app_secret,  
));

// Get the current user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Login Dialog
if (!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => $scope,
    'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
    ));

    print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
 }
       ?>
```

the most important for add permission is this part :

```
        $scope = 'email,publish_actions';
```

you can find all about the extended permissions in this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions

Comment: Hi. But this solution you provided is not what I need at all. All I want is that in my personal web page I retrieve my personal Facebook profile statuses and finally display, lets say the recent 5. That's it. There is no authentication of others users or anything like that.